# How to connect to VNC using vbs script?

Tags: shell, vbscript

How can I connect to VNC server using current dir instead of static.
If I use - `oShell.Run """C:\Users\Admin\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\test\bin\Debug\tvnviewer.exe"" 10.73.240.112"` everything is OK.

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim sCurPath 
sCurPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".") 
oShell.Run sCurPath & "\tvnviewer.exe" 10.73.240.112
WScript.Sleep 500
oShell.SendKeys "keepout" & chr(13)
```

Comment: Please compare the two statements. The solution is right under your nose.

Comment: found out.... """" & sCurPath & """" & "10.73.240.112"